# Borrado en cascada con filtro

Tags: hibernate

Buenos dias, soy nuevo en Hibernate y tengo una duda con los borrados en cascada.

Quiero saber si es posible que el borrado en cascada se realice en función del valor de un campo, me explico.

Tengo las entidades Pais (id,nombre) y Provincia(id,nombre,pais,habilitado), con una relacion 0 a n, por la cual podria haber provincias que teniendo un pais asociado, dicho pais es posible que no existiese, en cuyo caso, el valor de habilitado para la entidad Provincia seria "false".

El caso es que quiero saber si es posible definir la entidad de alguna manera que cuando se realice el borrado de un pais, solo me borre las provincias que teniendo asociado dicho pais, tengan el valor de habilitado a "true". Con lo que se hasta ahora, me elimina todas las provincias.

Entidad Pais:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Pais")
public class PaisEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @Column
   private Stringnombre;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
   @JoinColumn(name = "pais")
   private List<ProvinciaEntity> listaProvincias;
```

Entidad Provincia

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Provincia")
public class ProvinciaEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String nombre;

    @Column
    private Boolean habilitado;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pais")
    private PaisEntity pais;
```

No se si debo cambiar alguna anotacion o añadir algun atributo en las anotaciones existentes.

un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Esto viene de la integridad referencial de las bases de datos. Básicamente, si tienes un campo de una tabla referenciando al ID de otra tabla, y estableciendo la relación por una foreign key, las opciones de valor para ese campo son:

- Un ID de la tabla referenciada.
- `null`, si ese campo es opcional.

Así que, si borras un registro de la tabla referenciada que tiene referencias, las opciones son:

- Borrar los registros que la referencian.
- Poner la referencia a `null`.
- Lanzar un error.

JPA reproduce ese comportamiento (hay que recordar que por debajo puede tener la foreign key), no hay forma de cambiarlo. No puedes borrar el pais sin borrar la provincia o al menos ponerle la referncia a `null`.

La solución obvia es, antes de borrar un país (¿cada cuánto vas a tener que borrar un país? No es que desaparezcan paises cada día<sup>1</sup>), recorrer todas las provincias y, para aquellas que interesen, poner su campo de "pais" a `null` para que no les afecte el borrado.

Existe una anotación `@PreRemove` que permite marcar un método para que se ejecute antes de la eliminación de un entity. Un `@PreRemove` en `Pais` es un buen sitio para poner esa lógica.

---

<sup>1</sup>Aunque solo se trate de que dejas de hacer negocios con un país, a) lo más normal es simplemente deshabilitar el pais para no perder información y b) no será muy frecuente.

Comment: Ok, gracias @SJuan76, echare un vistazo al [@PreRemove]. Lo de Pais y Provincias era ejemplo, por no poner presupuestos, cargos, albaranes...